# Cannot load driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver weblogic 12C

Tags: sql-server, debugging, weblogic

I have a weblogic 12C server which is trying to connect to a MSSQL 2014 DB. I encountered the following issue :

> Cannot load driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

I have already check the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905156/cannot-load-driver-com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sqlserverdriver-weblogic-10g)

The suggested solution does not apply to me as in `D:\wls12210\wlserver\common\bin`, it does not contain the `commEnv.cmd` file for me to add the new classpath in.

A look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24367/third_party_drivers.htm#JDBCA233) suggests `Edit the commEnv.cmd/sh script in WL_HOME/common/bin` which is the same as the suggest solution

Where  is the misssing `commEnv.cmd`in weblogic 12c ??

Answer (score 2):

From weblogic 1221 documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/JDBCA/third_party_drivers.htm#JDBCA233) :

> To use third-party JDBC drivers that are not installed with WebLogic Server, you can add them to the DOMAIN_HOME/lib directory, where DOMAIN_HOME represents the directory in which the WebLogic Server domain is configured. The default path is ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains. For more information, see "Adding JARs to the Domain /lib Directory" in Developing Applications for Oracle WebLogic Server.

Please try as mentioned. I assumed you are using version weblogic 12.2.1 based on the directory structure in the post. When searching for anything in weblogic documentation, I usually search with weblogic version in the search query so it may take you to relevant weblogic documentation(obviously oracle has documentation for several versions). In this case I'm not sure if anything has changed between the versions, but anyway its a good thing to use the version in search query first.